# plus sign not working in widget "Header: Nav Menu"

Tags: menus, headers

I installed a new WP site with 3.1.2.  The way I set menu/header on my other sites was with the widget "Header: Nav Menu".  When I go to that widget now, clicking the + sign to the left of "Items" doesn't add the new item.

I'm thinking it's a browser compatibility problem, but I've tried FireFox 4, Chrome 11, and IE 8.

Update 05/25 with Sample picture:

[image]

I believe what used to happen is that when I clicked the plus-sign (pointed to by red-arrow), a new gray box would appear, where I could enter a new URL.  But absolutely nothing is happening when I click the plus-sign.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what plus sign you mean. Could you add a screen shot?

Adding item to a menu needs **two action**: 1. Mark the checkbox, 2. Click *Add to Menu*.

[image]

[View full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPdk3.png)

If you have trouble on the widget page, try to activate the accessibility mode available in the screen options.

Comment: Added picture in "update" of original post; didn't even know Stackexchange supported upload of pics!

Comment: @NealWalters That is not a part of the regular WordPress code. A plugin or a theme option? URL?

Comment: if i read correctly he said a widget?? who knows. Either way you should use the native system it works way better

Comment: I guess it's a widget in the Semiologic theme.  I still get confused about what is "standard" and what is a widget; they don't seem to get labeled as 'add-ons' when you use them.  I just know it used to work, and now it doesn't.  I do know it's dangerous to use widgets that go-away when you switch themes.

Comment: I'll try the Semiologic forum; here is where their widget is described: http://www.semiologic.com/software/nav-menus/